# MySQL/Foreach errors

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to concatenate a $sql string through a foreach loop, like so:

```
$sql = "select ISBN, title, price
            from bookdescriptions
            where ";

    foreach ($bookArray as $ISBN => $qty) {
        $sql .=  " ISBN = $ISBN or ";
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)- 2);
    }
```

where $ISBN, $bookArray, and $qty have all already been initialized.

What I'm trying to do (this is for an assignment) is to retrieve the ISBN for each ISBN in the cart.

However, I'm getting an error saying the foreach argument is not valid. Can someone spot the error or perhaps suggest a better solution?

Comment: The error means `$bookArray` is not really an array. Where do you get that from?

Comment: Why don't you use `where ISBN in (...)` instead of a bunch of `OR`s?

Comment: Can you print_r($bookArray) and add as Output in your code?

Comment: Yes `IN` Query is better than Multiple `OR`

Comment: $bookArray: `$qty = $bookArray[$ISBN];` and the $bookArray variable is used to add or delete ISBNs.

Comment: Can you just put code for `$bookArray` Generator code like `mysql_query `or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use something like this**

```
$sql = "SELECT ISBN, title, price
        FROM bookdescriptions
        WHERE TRUE AND ";

    $bookArray = array(
        array('ISBN' => 123, 'QTY'=> 10),
        array('ISBN' => 125, 'QTY'=> 10),
        array('ISBN' => 545, 'QTY'=> 10),
        array('ISBN' => 654, 'QTY'=> 10),
        array('ISBN' => 846, 'QTY'=> 10)
    );

    $isbn = array();
    foreach ($bookArray as $row) {
        array_push($isbn, $row['ISBN']);
    }

    $isbn = implode("','", $isbn);

    if ( count($isbn) > 0 ) {
        $sql .=  " ISBN IN( '$isbn' ) ";
    }

    echo $sql;
```

Comment: Your `foreach` argument is the same as in the question, how will this fix the error he's getting?

Comment: You forgot `implode(', ', $ISBN)`.

Comment: This was a response to code prior to correction. I will try this and see again.

Comment: @McGinger now what is the issue in given correction? please explain.

Comment: This code worked as it should! However, I'd want to display the ISBN and the QTY in a table; how would I do this since they are in arrays?

Thank you very much for your help by the way. I asked my prof for help and got the above code...

Answer (score 0):

This might not fix your error, but you need to move this line

```
 $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)- 2);
```

out of the loop like this:

```
$sql = "select ISBN, title, price
            from bookdescriptions
            where ";
foreach ($bookArray as $ISBN => $qty) {
    $sql .=  " ISBN = $ISBN or ";
}
   $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)- 2);
```

I am guessing that you want to get rid of the last "OR" but by including it in the loop, you are deleting it right after you added it. You only need to remove the last occurrence of OR since it would invalidate the where clause of the SQL statement

Comment: This is true, but it won't fix an error that the argument to `foreach` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize I had it in the foreach loop! That'll solve errors later but the argument for the loop is still invalid.